# How to encrypt Sql connection string?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I have a WCF Service which connect to Sql Server 2005 to retrieve and send data according to the method invoked.

Currently I am using a hard coded sql connection string in .cs file to create a connection.

Let me know what is the best way to use the connection string or where i place the connection string?

Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the connection string is in the web.config, you can use the DataProtectionConfigurationProvider and RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider to encrypt it.

[Encrypting Connection Strings](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/02/15/encryptingconnstring.html)